# How to set for multiple dropdowns an already selected value in angular

Tags: angular

So I have an object coming from the backend that looks something like this

```
[
 {key: '1', value: 'OK'},
 {key: '2', value: 'NOT OK'},
 {key: '3', value: 'NOT OK'},
 {key: '4', value: 'NOT OK'},
 {key: '5', value: 'NOT OK'}
]
```

I have an html template like this

```
<table style="width:100%" *ngIf="show">
            <tr>
                <th>Day Counter</th>
                <td *ngFor="let obj of objectToArrayOfObjects">{{obj.key}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <td *ngFor="let i of nrOfInputsArr" >
                        <mat-form-field style="width: 35px; height: 15px"
                                        appearance="outline" >
                                <mat-label></mat-label>


                                <mat-select
                                        [(ngModel)]="theKeysOfTheObjToArrayOfObjects"
                                        style="width:35px">
                                                 <mat-option
                                                         *ngFor="let options of statusOptions"
                                                         [value] = 'options'
                                                         (click)="AddToArray(options, i)">
                                                     {{options.value}}
                                                 </mat-option>
                                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                </td>
             </tr>
    </table>
```

And A typescript file like this :

```
    statusOptions = [
        { value :     'OK'},
        { value : 'NOT OK'},
    ]

      showDaysOfSustainabilityCheck() {
                console.log(this.data.processedDays)
                console.log(this.objectToArrayOfObjects,'iterate');
                console.log(this.theValuesOfTheObjToArrayOfObjects,'2iterate')
                this.isDaysOfSustainabilityCheckNeeded = !this.isDaysOfSustainabilityCheckNeeded;
                this.data.sustainableActionRequired = true;
      }
```

```
 /*
//console.log(this.data.processedDays);
{
    "1": "OK",
    "2": "NOT OK",
    "3": "NOT OK",
    "4": "NOT OK",
    "5": "NOT OK"
}
//console.log(this.objectToArrayOfObjects); 

[
 {key: '1', value: 'OK'},
 {key: '2', value: 'NOT OK'},
 {key: '3', value: 'NOT OK'},
 {key: '4', value: 'NOT OK'},
 {key: '5', value: 'NOT OK'}
]

//console.log(this.theValuesOfTheObjToArrayOfObjects);
['OK', 'NOT OK', 'NOT OK', 'NOT OK', 'NOT OK'] 
*/
```

What exactly is happening?

When a user selects yes or no from the table, the data is processed and saved in the back end. My goal is that when a specific post that I have already done is activated. What I want is for the yes or no answers to remain selected when we open the respective ticket that the user created.

Based on an input, a number of dropdowns are opened, all of which have a yes or no answer.

So my problem is that when I make the call from the backend, these answers that were later selected, are not saved in the dropdown

I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created this simple example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-5gzgxq?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts) for you with fake backend service call. If you have any additional questions about Angular lifecycle hooks and data processing, please use comments section.

If it is not working for you. Im adding the code also here.

### Template

```
<table *ngIf="showTable" style="width:100%; padding: 30px;">
  <tr>
    <th>Day Counter</th>
    <td style="text-align: center;" *ngFor="let key of dataKeys">
      {{ key }}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Status</th>
    <td *ngFor="let entry of currentData">
      <mat-form-field style="width: 120px;" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label></mat-label>
        <mat-select
          [(value)]="entry.value"
          (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange()"
        >
          <mat-option
            [value]="status.value"
            *ngFor="let status of availableStatuses"
          >
            {{ status.value }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Component data

```
enum Status {
  OK = 'OK',
  NOK = 'NOT OK',
}

interface EntryStatus {
  value: Status;
  viewValue?: string;
}

interface DataEntry {
  key: string;
  value: Status;
}

  showTable = true;

  currentData: DataEntry[] = [
    { key: '1', value: Status.OK },
    { key: '2', value: Status.NOK },
    { key: '3', value: Status.NOK },
    { key: '4', value: Status.NOK },
    { key: '5', value: Status.NOK },
  ];

  dataKeys = this.currentData.map((entry) => entry.key);

  availableStatuses: EntryStatus[] = [
    { value: Status.OK },
    { value: Status.NOK },
  ];
```

Comment: this is an exccelent example, but I don't really know how to implement it into my case : (

Comment: Have you been able to make it work already? If not, what it your current blocker? Data after refresh are incorrect, not updated or not selected as you would expect? You have to understand what is the current state of all component properties / variables / data after processing the data and after every angular lifecycle hook.

Maybe be more specific or provide additional code samples. Otherwise, I am not sure I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

**NOT** use `(click)` in options. use `[(ngModel)]="obj.value"`

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of objectToArrayOfObjects">
  {{obj.key}}
  <!--see that the variable you want "binding" are
            obj.value
  -->
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="obj.value">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let options of statusOptions"
        [value] = 'options'>
           {{options.value}}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</div>

Just to check the values:
<pre>
 {{objectToArrayOfObjects|json}}
</pre>
```

Now in submit you send the objectToArrayOfObject to the service than change the dbs